# Issues with importing Vuelidate Library

Tags: javascript, sails.js, vuelidate

As a part of implementing Form Validation, I want to use Vuelidate library in a Sails.js page. The page gets the Vue code by using this webpage.page.js:

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

parasails.registerPage('web-page', {
    data: {
        message: '',
        class: ''
    },
    validations: {
       // For Vuelidate
       message: {
         required,
       },
       class: {
         required,
       },
    }, 
});
```

, which is linked to this webpage.ejs View Template:

```
<div id="web-page">
  <div class="container d-flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div class="heading-container">
            <p class="h2">Heading</p>
        </div>
        <form action="/someaction" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.name.$error }">
                <label 
                      for="name" class="form__label">Name</label>
                <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form__input"
                      name="name"
                      v-model.trim="$v.name.$model"/>
            </div>
           <div class="error" v-if="!$v.name.required">Field is required</div>
           <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.class.$error }">
                <label for="class" class="form__label">Class</label>
                 <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form__input"
                      name="class"
                      v-model.trim="$v.class.$model"/>
           </div>
           <div class="error" v-if="!$v.class.required">Field is required</div>
           <button class="btn btn-success text-white" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<%- /* Expose locals as `window.SAILS_LOCALS` :: */ exposeLocalsToBrowser() %>
```

This gives an error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'. I have the Vuelidate npm package installed. Thus, how can I import the Vuelidate library to get this working?

Comment: Is there a problem with this question?
Have I left out any detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Sails web template, you need to import Vuelidate dist files `validators.min.js` and `vuelidate.min.js` into the `assets/dependencies` folder. After that, Grunt imports the files and you'll be able to use them globally without `import` because they will be available in the browser.

Check the documentation section `The browser-ready bundle is also provided in the package.`:

https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-usage

Comment: Is it justified to depend on window Object for using Vuelidate?Wouldn't it cause cross-browser issues?

Comment: An alternative is to replace the assets structure to use multipage Vue CLI in order to compile assets easily. For example, I created recently a package `npm i sails-hook-nuxt` to use Nuxt.

Comment: Will look into that suggestion, @jorge